# iOS OpenTok audio-video call has video disabled with an undocumented reason on iOS Simulator and routed sessions

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, opentok, tokbox

While testing on the iOS Simulator a vide call with routed sessions the user gets its video disabled with an undocumented reason.

On the latest version of OpenTok 2.15.3 we can see that the possible reasons for video being disabled are:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(int32_t, OTSubscriberVideoEventReason) {
    OTSubscriberVideoEventPublisherPropertyChanged = 1,
    OTSubscriberVideoEventSubscriberPropertyChanged = 2,
    OTSubscriberVideoEventQualityChanged = 3
};
```

on the iOS 11 simulator, right after trying to subscribe I'm getting the video enabled with `OTSubscriberVideoEventReason == 2`, right after it gets disabled with `OTSubscriberVideoEventReason == 4` and then I get the following error on `subscriberDidDisconnectFromStream`:

```
Internal error -- WebRTC subscriber error. 
Failed to set remote offer sdp: 
Session error code: ERROR_CONTENT. 
Session error description: Failed to set remote video description send 
parameters.. 
kPCFailureSetRemoteDescription
```

The docs suggested trying to resubscribe, or reconnect... resubscribing didn't work. Furthermore it's only happening on the simulator, which makes me think that there is nothing really wrong with the setup, but the real question here is, what is the `OTSubscriberVideoEventReason == 4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

Yes, unfortunately, we didn't publicly document this specific case(sorry about that). We plan on adding this in the 2.16.0 release.

The reason that `OTSubscriberVideoEventReason=4` is dispatched is when the video in the subscriber stream was disabled because the stream uses a video codec (such as H.264) that's not supported on the simulator.

Comment: Thanks Manik, just for my information... will that be addressed in future versions? Or the simulator will  not be supported anymore?

Comment: The H.264 support for the codec on the simulator has to be added by Apple so until then we can't add it.  Please note that this should only be effecting the simulator and not the physical iOS devices.